# Browser back button dissabling issue

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using the following java script to disable the browser back button for my QUIZ application. Which is working fine in chrome but not in IE. Could you please suggest the change for below code or the code snippet which disables the browser back button in Both IE 9 and Chrome. Push state is not supported by IE 9.

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >
history.pushState(null, null, 'instructions.aspx');
window.addEventListener('popstate', function (event) {
history.pushState(null, null, 'instructions.aspx');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work in `IE` ...

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function noBack() 
    { 
         window.history.forward(); 
    }
</script>
```

Just [googling](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/560553/Howplustoplusdisableplusbackplusbuttonplusmozillap) a bit...